# Xcode Instruments Leak coming from UIDeviceRGBColor

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks

I have a leak coming from UIDeviceRGBColor. The responsible frame is +[UIColor allocWithZone:]. I am not using ARC.

The leak is coming from the method below.

```
- (void) lAction
{
MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;
mapRegion.center = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.05;
mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.05;

[mapView setRegion:mapRegion animated: YES];

SettingsViewController *settingsViewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] 
initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
```

**The leak is coming from this next line:**

```
[self presentModalViewController: settingsViewController animated:YES];
```

**Then the method finishes like this:**

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:40.0/255.0 
green:43.0/255.0 blue:46.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}
```

Anyone know how to fix this? Thank you all!

Comment: If you're only going to wait 8 minutes in between posting questions, then you should try to do a better job of finding the answers yourself before posting.

Comment: Thanks much - trying to dive into the nebula of memory mgmt. Gone through about a thousand tuts, and am gathering more knowledge from the experts.

Comment: You can see from my post that I am not using ARC. Would you recommend that I try to convert my project?

Comment: @Brandon Have you found any solution?

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
SettingsViewController *settingsViewController = [[[SettingsViewController alloc] 
initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

In order to satisfy the commenter, the explanation is simply that if you're not using ARC, whenever you call `alloc`, the retain count of the returned object is set to 1. You are responsible for releasing it. One easy way to do that is call autorelease on it which will automatically release it at the end of the main run loop (unless you're managing your own autorelease pool, but I won't get into that). You do want to make sure that as long as you need to use an object your code has something retaining it, in this case when you call

```
[self presentModalViewController: settingsViewController animated:YES];
```

an extra retain is called on the settingViewController, so you don't have to worry about it getting dealloced when your method finishes.

I find memory management in Objective-C pretty easy, but it does require extra code and everyone uses ARC these days. If you're just making a few small changes to an existing code base, there is no need to switch to ARC, but if you're going to continue working with the code base for some time, it will be more time efficient to switch. It is pretty straightforward to do, as Xcode will do most of the work for you. (See here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: This is not an answer. Please provide an explanation as to how this solves this problem. Otherwise, this would be better suited as comment.